# Is there a way to use @GeneratedValue so that it works both with sequence and auto-increment?

Tags: mysql, oracle, jpa, mariadb

I'm developing an application that must be deployed in several environments, using different RDBMSs, namely MySQL, MariaDB and Oracle. This implies different modes of ID generation (auto-increment vs sequence).

JPA is supposed to allow for the abstraction from the RDBMS. However, I don't know **how to configure the `@Id` field so that it can work with both auto-increment and sequences**.

```
// Auto-increment
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

// Sequence
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Use an `orm.xml` to define such things. Then you can have one file for one database, and another file for the other database ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL or MariaDB but from a quick search it seems they do have identity columns.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, they do. Oracle, on the other hand, does not until v12. And Maria has sequences since v10.3. But I'm looking for a solution that works with all of them.

Comment: How long do you really need to support 11g though? 12.1 came out in 2014, and it’s already been superseded by 12.2 and 18c. When you say the application needs to run on Oracle, how far are we going back?

Comment: @WilliamRobertsonThat's an interesting question. I'm so used to having all my clients using sequences that I didn't realize the feature was so widely available. Just making a quick check with my clients to see if 11g support is needed. However, I think an answer would still be interesting, even if only for the intellectual need (and also because Oracle and Maria are not the only RDBMSs).

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Just to confirm, the identity JPA strategy works fine with Oracle 12+ when the column has been defined as an identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, I found an answer and it appears that some companies have met with the same difficulty. The answer is currently available [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/).

The main ideas are to:

1. design your entities using the `SEQUENCE` generation strategy;
2. provide a JPA XML mapping file that overrides the Java-based annotation mapping;
3. load this mapping file when running with MySQL (or other sequence-incompatible RDBMS).

This is possible because:

> XML metadata may be used as an alternative to these annotations, or to override or augment annotations
>
> — JPA 2.1 specification, 11.1 Annotations for Object/Relational Mapping

For instance, quoting the example of the article I linked to above, the entity would be:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "sequence",
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "sequence",
        allocationSize = 10
    )
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity sake
}
```

And the mapping file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1"
        >
    <package>com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.global</package>
    <entity class="Post" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id">
                <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

For more information on the technical aspects and on why not to use the `AUTO` strategy, please refer to [the article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/).